# Workaround for CSS variables in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, outsystems

I'm currently developing a web application in Outsystems in which I have the need to customize the CSS, in which I'm using variables. I need to guarantee the app works cross-browser, including in Internet Explorer. IE doesn't support CSS variables, as you can see in the picture below from [this source](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables).

[image]

Since I have to use CSS variables, is there any workaround for the usage of variables in IE?

Comment: you could use sass or less instead

Comment: You can also take a look here : https://github.com/postcss/postcss

Comment: There is a polifill for browsers which don't  yet support css variables also for Internet explorer and edge: https://gist.github.com/stramel/91d05253f801f771da38b3bc7d3c765f

Comment: You can check this one: https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill

Answer (score 62):

Yes there is a way, the same way you make any css compatible: use a specific css fallback that is supported by the browser.

```
body {
  --text-color: red;
}

body {
  color: red; /* default supported fallback style */
  color: var(--text-color); /* will not be used by any browser that doesn't support it, and will default to the previous fallback */
}
```

This solution is incredibly redundant and 'almost' defeats the purpose of css variables....BUT it is necessary for browser compatibility. Doing this would essentially make the css variables useless but I implore you to still use them because it will serve as an important reminder to the fact that these values are referenced elsewhere and need to be updated in all cases, otherwise you forget to update every related occurrence of 'color' and then you have inconsistent styling because relevant css values are out of sync. The variable will serve more as a comment but a very important one.

Comment: Agreed, that it defeats the purpose of variables - IF you must ensure consistent experience on all browser. However, this can still be used effectively to provide a "default" theme for browsers that do not support it, and custom theme for browsers that do support it.

Answer (score 51):

There is a polyfill, which enables almost complete support for CSS variables in IE11:
https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties
(i am the author)

The script makes use of the fact that IE has minimal custom properties support where properties can be defined and read out with the cascade in mind.
`.myEl {-ie-test:'aaa'} // only one dash allowed! "-"`
then read it in javascript:
`getComputedStyle( querySelector('.myEl') )['-ie-test']`

From the README:

> ***Features***
>
> - handles dynamic added html-content
> - handles dynamic added , -elements
> - chaining `--bar:var(--foo)`
> - fallback `var(--color, blue)`
> - :focus, :target, :hover
> - js-integration:
>
>   - `style.setProperty('--x','y')`
>   - `style.getPropertyValue('--x')`
>   - `getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('--inherited')`
> - Inline styles: `<div ie-style="--color:blue"...`
> - cascade works
> - inheritance works
> - under 3k (min+gzip) and dependency-free

#### Demo:

https://rawcdn.githack.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties/b851ec2b6b8e336a78857b570d9c12a8526c9a91/test.html

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm...
I have downloaded the JS file and just imported that in my Angular 8 application polyfills.js file.

Comment: Hey @TobiasBuschor, How can I access the values of the initiall css Variables.
I have document.styleSheets => sheet.cssRules => rule.style  then I filter that final array only keeping properties that begin with "--". I updated to also look for properties that start with "-ieVar-" or "-ie-" but I that finds nothing in IE.

My approach allows me to add a css variable anywhere in my codebase, collecting the values on load to allow me to swap between a light and dark mode so I would like to avoid hardcoding all the variable names to use when swapping

Answer (score 6):

In case someone comes across this,  has a similar issue where I had it set like this.

```
a {
  background: var(--new-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I added the background colour before the variable so if that didn't load it fell back on the hex.

```
a {
  background: #3279B8;
  background: var(--new-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Totally defeating the whole point of using variables in the first place. Can't everybody just agree to stop using IE once and for all? lol

Comment: Yeah I 100% agree but sadly there is still some people out there using it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, so long as you're processing root-level custom properties (IE9+).

- **GitHub**: https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill
- **NPM**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-vars-ponyfill
- **Demo**: https://codepen.io/jhildenbiddle/pen/ZxYJrR

From the README:

> **Features**
>
> - Client-side transformation of CSS custom properties to static values
> - Live updates of runtime values in both modern and legacy browsers
> - Transforms `<link>`, `<style>`, and `@import` CSS
> - Transforms relative `url()` paths to absolute URLs
> - Supports chained and nested `var()` functions
> - Supports `var()` function fallback values
> - Supports web components / shadow DOM CSS
> - Watch mode auto-updates on `<link>` and `<style>` changes
> - UMD and ES6 module available
> - TypeScript definitions included
> - Lightweight (6k min+gzip) and dependency-free
>
> **Limitations**
>
> - Custom property support is limited to `:root` and `:host` declarations
> - The use of var() is limited to property values (per [W3C specification](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill))

Here are a few examples of what the library can handle:

**Root-level custom properties**

```
:root {
    --a: red;
}

p {
    color: var(--a);
}
```

**Chained custom properties**

```
:root {
    --a: var(--b);
    --b: var(--c);
    --c: red;
}

p {
    color: var(--a);
}
```

**Nested custom properties**

```
:root {
    --a: 1em;
    --b: 2;
}

p {
    font-size: calc(var(--a) * var(--b));
}
```

**Fallback values**

```
p {
    font-size: var(--a, 1rem);
    color: var(--b, var(--c, var(--d, red))); 
}
```

**Transforms `<link>`, `<style>`, and `@import` CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/absolute/path/to/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../relative/path/to/style.css">

<style>
    @import "/absolute/path/to/style.css";
    @import "../relative/path/to/style.css";
</style>
```

**Transforms web components / shadow DOM**

```
<custom-element>
  #shadow-root
    <style>
      .my-custom-element {
        color: var(--test-color);
      }
    </style>
    <div class="my-custom-element">Hello.</div>
</custom-element>
```

For the sake of completeness: [w3c specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/)

Hope this helps.

(Shameless self-promotion: Check)

Answer (score 0):

Make a seperate .css file for your variables. Copy/paste the contents of the variable.css file to the end of your main.css file. Find and replace all the variable names in the main.css file to the hex code for those variables. For example: ctrl-h to find var(--myWhiteVariable) and replace with #111111.

Side note: if you keep the :root{ } in the main.css file and just comment it out, you can use that to track those hex codes later if you want to update your fallback colors.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is declaring colors in a JS file (in my case I'm using react) and then just use the variable you defined in the JS file.

For example:

- in globals.js

```
export const COLORS = {
  yellow: '#F4B400',
  yellowLight: '#F4C849',
  purple: '#7237CC',
  purple1: '#A374EB',
}
```

- in your file

```
import { COLORS } from 'globals'
```

and then just use `COLORS.yellow`, `COLORS.purple`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

```
body {
  --text-color : red; /* --text-color 정의 */
}    

body {
   color: var(--text-color, red); /* --text-color 정의되지 않으면 red로 대체됨 */
}

body {
   color: var(--text-color, var(--text-color-other, blue));
   /* --text-color, --text-color-other 가 정의되지 않으면 blue로 대체됨 */
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There is no way yet in "normal" css but take a look at sass/scss or less.

here is a scss example

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

Comment: SASS variables and CSS variables are different! SASS variables are not dynamic and cannot be changed after they are compiled. CSS variables can be changed after compilation.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend setting your css variables as sass variables, then using sass interpolation to render the color in your elements.

```
:root {    
    --text-color: #123456;
}

$text-color: var(--text-color);

body {
    color: #{$text-color};
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question at all. CSS variables aren't supported in older browsers such as IE. Using your code doesn't provide a fallback value, it just assigns the same CSS variable to body as well. Try running this fiddle in a browser that doesn't support CSS variables: https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrndwgn/8syno0qx/

Answer (score -23):

If im not wrong there is a workaround, the CSS #ID Selector. Which should work for IE > 6 I guess.. So you can

```
.one { };
<div class="one">
```

should work as

```
#one {};
<div id="one">
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question.

Comment: That's very far from using a variable. Imagine that you want to use the same color for a background and for a font face. You need to define two properties and hard code the color value. Now scale that up to 20 properties. Hard to manage right? if we would have a way to set it as a variable, you would have to change it only once.