# Working with var css in internet explorer using Angular 7

Tags: angular

Css variable working fine with chrome but not in IE, I'm trying to do this:

```
:root {
    --primary-color: #015a82;
    --background-color: #015a82;
    --text-color: #fff;
    --secondary-color: #6d6d6d;
}

body {
color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

But it is not supported in Internet Explorer, I tried to implement `postcss-loader` but it seems like not compatible with Angular 7, any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Workaround for CSS variables in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955538/workaround-for-css-variables-in-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was very simple.

1- `npm i css-vars-ponyfill --save`.

2- in app.component.ts you have to do this:

```
import cssVars from 'css-vars-ponyfill';


constructor() {... }

ngOnInit() {
    cssVars();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd to put it into my component, but that seems to work!

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just appended the below script in index html head tag and it's working

```
<script>window.MSInputMethodContext && document.documentMode && document.write('<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties@4.1.0/ie11CustomProperties.min.js"><\x2fscript>');</script>
```