# Set custom style attribue doesn't work in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, styles

I have this simple Javascript code to change custom CSS attribute

```
var root = document.documentElement;
root.style.setProperty("--custom-bg", "#4f5357");
```

This works fine in Firefox Google Chrome but it doesn't work in IE 11  also tried

```
root['--custom-bg'] = "#4f5357";
root.attr("--custom-bg", "#4f5357");
root.style['--custom-bg'] = "#4f5357";
```

none of them worked .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE11 **doesn't** support css custom properties, therefore it doesn't supports this `setProperty` method.

Checkout this [css-vars-ponyfill](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill), which aims to add basic support.

Answer (score 0):

Answered: [Workaround for CSS variables in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955538/workaround-for-css-variables-in-ie/57000620#57000620)

This was the best solution for me, no installation is needed:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ie11-custom-properties

Copy this to the head of your html:

```
<script>window.MSInputMethodContext && document.documentMode && document.write('<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties@4.1.0/ie11CustomProperties.min.js"><\x2fscript>');</script>
```