# Angular: Change Font Size options for users in IE11 (CSS-Variables)

Tags: html, css, angular, internet-explorer-11, css-variables

I am developing an Angular application. From the webpage, the user can select a small, medium or large fonts (medium is the default) and based on that we have to change the font size all over the page. Now for other browsers, I can use `var()` but it is not compatible with IE. So one way of doing it is manually applying font-size in every single HTML tags either using `ngStyle` or `ngClass`. But I find this method really bad. Is there another way of doing it? I don't want to write this piece of code in every single component.

```
<div class="hm-header-title" [ngStyle]="fontSize()"></div>
```

```
fontSize(){
    return this.ieStyleService.fontSize() // ex return {'font-size': '11px'}
}
```

Comment: Does IE not allow the user to just increase magnification?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429937/ie11-does-a-polyfill-script-exist-for-css-variables

Comment: I understand that for other browsers you are using the CSS-variables that is not supported in IE 11. I try to search about it and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57000620/10309381). In which a [pollyfill](https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties) is suggested for CSS Variables. I suggest you try to check it and see whether you can implement it in your project. It may help to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying it manually for IE alone.

```
changeFontSize(fontSize){
    ieFontSizeClass=[
        '.someClass1 *',
        '.someClass2 *',
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ]

    if(this.isIE()){
        ieFontSizeClass.forEach((className: string) => {
                let elements = document.querySelectorAll(className) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;

                let i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    elements[i].style.fontSize = fontSize;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

NOTE that adding * is important because it will be applied to all the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cascading feature of the CSS or/and em/rem.

The idea is quite simple in theory (but might need some rework in practice)

Define font-size for the body:

```css
body{font-size: 16px;}
```

Define font-size for elements you want to have dynamic fonts like:

```css
.lbl{font-size: 1rem}
```

Now, when you want to change the font-size of the label, you need just to change the font-size property of the body. Everything else will be done automatically.

Take a note that you can use float values as well to get better results:

```css
.lbl {font-size: 1.33rem}
```

About rem/em:

> rem and em units are computed into pixel values by the browser, based
> on font sizes in your design. em units are based on the font size of
> the element they're used on. rem units are based on the font size of
> the HTML element. em units can be influenced by font size inheritance
> from any parent element

```js
const $btn = document.getElementById("tgl");
$btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle("large");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body.large {
  font-size: 32px;
}

label {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <label>I have dynamic font size</label>
    <button id="tgl">Toggle font size</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried the following because I regard IE11 as "almost dead" and I am nowadays ignoring it because my target audience is fairly controlled and I can divert them away from it.

In your situation where you do need to support it, I would try setting the font size at the very top of the application:

```
:host {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Then have all your CSS throughout the entire application use rem (root em units) so that they refer back to the root font size:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

IE11 does support rem: https://caniuse.com/rem

Then you need to change the root's font-size and everything else will inherit from that. Something like:

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty('font-size', '12px');
```

or even directly on the DOM:

```
document.style.setProperty('font-size', '12px');
```

These are just ideas and I am sorry I don't have time to investigate this further, but I hope it moves you on.